# Syntax error while trying to create a foreign key

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax, foreign-keys

I'm creating a table with a foreign key but I get a syntax error:

```
drop table if exists enviada;

create table if not exists enviada 
(
    destinatario_email varchar(300),
    destinatario_nome varchar(200),
    destinatario_cpf_cnpj varchar(14),
    data_envio datetime,
    remetente varchar(50),
    assunto varchar(200),
    foreign key (assunto) references (email_html) assunto,
    primary key (destinatario_email, destinatario_cpf_cnpj, data_envio, assunto)
);
```

```
sqlite> .read ".\\Scripts SQL\\esquema_email.sql"
Parse error near line 8: near "(": syntax error
  o, assunto),     foreign key (assunto) references (email_html) assunto );
                                      error here ---^
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
references email_html (assunto)
```

Comment: Sure. That's what some uninterrupted hours do to an old brain

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) shows you that you have to switch column in parentehsis with the table name like

```
create table if not exists enviada 
(
    destinatario_email varchar(300),
    destinatario_nome varchar(200),
    destinatario_cpf_cnpj varchar(14),
    data_envio datetime,
    remetente varchar(50),
    assunto varchar(200),
    foreign key (assunto) references assunto (email_html) ,
    primary key (destinatario_email, destinatario_cpf_cnpj, data_envio, assunto)
);
```